# Put the `response.data` value into the `setState[]` array

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, use-state, swr

I want to put `swr` data into setState[]
I have code like this.

```
const { data } = useSWR('/api/data', fetcher);
const [contents, setcontents] = useState<Array<string>>([]);
```

How can I write code to put `data` in `setcontents[]` ?

Comment: If you just need to update the `contents` state a `setcontents(data)` should work. If `data` is an array of strings.

Comment: @LucaPizzini Yep data is a string. But I don't know how to put it in `State[]` .

Comment: As I said, using the `setcontents(data)` function. It should work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don’t need to do this. The `data` is already part of the component’s state, and SWR is managing it for you. You don’t need to transfer the data into another state variable.

Use `data` anywhere you were expecting to use `contents`, and it will work as you expected. You can choose a different name for the variable if you like:

```
const { data: contents } = useSWR(...)
```

Comment: This does not give us access to a `setData()`.

Comment: @C.Lewis If you need to manually update SWR's cache, you should usually use the [mutate function](https://swr.vercel.app/docs/mutation) that useSWR returns.

Answer (score 0):

You can use useEffect hook to solve this problem.

```
useEffect(() => {
    setcontents(data);
  }, [data]);
```